# Why does the trace work,but it doesnt addChild?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am having some problem with addChild onto stage. For some reason the code is tracing the results, but it is not adding Child, the child is just a picture file that sits in the library. It is imported into another class file.

Thanks for your time.

```
package  com.clark 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Listingdetailinfo extends MovieClip
    {
        private var somedata:Array;

        public function Listingdetailinfo(somedata:Array) 
        {
            trace("John");
            trace("Ben");
            trace("Top");
            trace("Benson");    

            var Bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8();
            addChild(Bolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Listingdetail class

```
package com.clark 
{
    import com.clark.Listingdetailinfo;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Listingdetail extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var s1:List = new List ();
        private var somedata:Array;

        public function Listingdetail()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);

            function onadded (event:Event):void
            {   
                s1.x=-10;
                s1.y=10;
                addChild(s1);
            }

            function teee():void
            {
                var tee:Listingdetailinfo = new Listingdetailinfo();
                addChild(tee);   
            }
        }    
    }       
}
```

Thanks for your time

edit:
From SearchVectorTest

```
public var lists:Array;
    lists =new Array (test[index].nobed,test[index].zip,test[index].Location,test[index].price);
            var addto:Listingdetailinfo = new Listingdetailinfo(lists);
```

In Listingdetailinfo

```
public var lists:Array;
    public function Listingdetailinfo(lists:Array) {

                trace("Ben");
        addChild(Holder);

    }
```

Comment: Yer, this is my first attempt, so am still learning how to arrange the codes etc. I will give that a go thanks.

Comment: I tried it, there is nothing added on the stage but this is what was traced [object Listing8]
[object Listingdetailinfo]
true

Comment: I added it, and it is null.

Comment: so now search where you should add it to stage as obviously it is not.

Comment: Ahh ok cool thanks, just 1 question, in the Listdetail class, i imported the Listingdetailinfo class into it. So i have to addChild again to make it go onto stage?

Comment: import does nothing it only adds piece of code, you have to instantiate and add to display list.

Comment: Ahhh ok, thanks, yer i was wondering about that but it requires an argument in that Listingdetail, i edited the code about with adding  the Listingdetailinfo to display but i am not sure what i need to put there. I will try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: can you try to set the width and height of your control before adding it to screen ? also can you trace Bolder.x/y/width/height on enterFrame ?

Answer (score 2):

your code is a mess that's for sure. if you have something that can be exported in library then this should work:

```
var bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8(); 
addChild(bolder); 
trace(bolder); 
trace(bolder.parent); 
trace(contains(bolder));
trace(bolder.stage);//will be non null when this and it's containers are on stage
if(bolder.parent) trace(bolder.parent.parent);
```

Importing the class alone does nothing, merely adds the code of the class, you have to use it by instantiating it

```
var detailInfo:Listingdetailinfo = new Listingdetailinfo();
addChild(detailInfo);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the Help, i instantiatied it, but 1 very weird thing is everything is added twice, and i tried  trace("John"); in the Listingdetailinfo class, and it was traced twice. And when i pass data from another class, it gives the data once, then trace null after it. For some reason it's doing everything twice.

Comment: Display object is like a tree and you add to it leaves and branches, so if something is traced more than once it means that more than once you have instantiated it.

Comment: :) Thanks for the tip! I will have a look at where it is going funny

Comment: I am still having problem with the display object, i tried for more than a whole day on trying to find out why the addChild is duplicated. I cant seem to find the reason. I edited the code above, it is in that "lists = new Array (data) and var addto:Listingdetailinfo" line when i have both lines, it is added twice, but i can't only have 1 line. Then the data won't pass through.